# d3 with jade template

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pug

I am new to both d3 and jade. I have jade template as below,

```
div(id='viz')
script(type="text/javascript")
  d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
      .attr('width', 600)
      .attr('height', 300)
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 300)
        .attr('cy', 150)
        .attr('r', 30)
        .attr('fill', '#26963c')
```

I am trying to add small circle in `div viz`. When page is loaded i dont see any circle, html code via inspector is as below,

```
<div id="viz"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><d3 body class="select"><div svg class="append"><div width 600 class="attr"></div><div height 300 class="attr"></div><div circle class="append"><div cx 300 class="attr"></div><div cy 150 class="attr"></div><div r 30 class="attr"></div><div fill #26963c class="attr"></div></div></div></d3></script>
```

Can anyone put some light on what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `.` dot after `script(type="text/javascript")`

```
div(id='viz')
script(type="text/javascript").
  d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
      .attr('width', 600)
      .attr('height', 300)
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 300)
        .attr('cy', 150)
        .attr('r', 30)
        .attr('fill', '#26963c')
```

[source](http://jade-lang.com/)